# Edit Page missing from App

Tags: lightning-web-components, app

I created an App and want to add LWC components to it. The Edit Page option is missing. Is there an option somewhere to activate ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only created a lightning app. You need to create flexipages now by navigating to `Setup -> Lightning App Builder` then create a app, home, record page.

Here you can add your custom/ standard components. Then assign this flexipage to your app created above.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_lab.htm&type=5&release=234

Comment: Thank you very much